# Can wider range (i.e. 600-700 MHz) antenna replace lower range (650-700 MHz) antenna?

Tags: wireless-communication

I had an appliance (wireless audio receiver), which has operational range 662-698 mhz (and had same ranged antenna exactly from factory), like this:

[image]

However, that antenna was broken accidentally and I want to replace the antenna, but can't find exactly that model. However, I've found a bit wider ranged antenna:  632-698 mhz

Can that work without problems? may i replace with that?

EDIT: exact model is: shure `ULXP4 (662-698 mhz)`: [Sophisticated, scalable
wireless solutions](https://web.archive.org/web/20140113201654/http://cdn.shure.com/brochure/upload/38/pdf_2010_ulx_brochure.pdf) (also here specs: [ULX Wireless System Specification Sheet](http://alss1.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ULX4PK.pdf))  and replacement antenna I want is: http://bit.do/fgergsadf

Comment: if the gains are similar chances are that the replacement antenna might work. I suggest that you update the post with your findings. Also I suggest updating post with `shura ulxp4 662-692` information too. Also is this a representative image of your receiver. https://media.sweetwater.com/api/i/f-webp__q-82__ha-c0cc13b301cfb33d__hmac-1156e178daf942303d4ca13b107209c404dcef3d/images/items/750/ULXP4-M1-large.jpg.auto.webp

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena Yes, I've updated, thank you very much. please, after that, combine all your comments into one post (which i wil mark and upvote ! ) thanks

Comment: I posted some additional information in the from answer. Also in trying to help you I also learned something new. That is FCC in US has reassigned the 600 MHz frequency spectrum to cellular communication. I don't this will affect you, but thus the reason the you cannot find 600MHz antenna's for wireless receivers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operational frequency operational range of the proposed antenna is within the frequency range of the old antenna. It should not be an issue from frequency standpoint. If the gains are similar chances are that the replacement antenna might work.

I also noticed the following statement for your alternative antenna.

[image]

So the alternative antenna is not design your UXLP4 wireless receiver. Wanted to make you aware of the differences.

I did get chance to review [ULX Wireless System User Guide](https://www.shureasia.com/productdocumentsfiles/default/discontinued/wireless/ulxwirelessuserguide-36fc66950413b32b410df0a3e73af99c.pdf) Looks like you might have other antenna options for your receiver. Some those options are listed below.

[image]

Depending on region you might have to select the appropriate regulatory transmit and receive frequency / channel

[image: transmit and receive Frequency / Channel]

On a side note United States of America, Federal Communication Commission (FCC) has reassigned the 600MHz frequency spectrum for cellular communication as licenses frequency band. Therefore as of October 2018 it is illegal to use unless authorized by the FCC. That most likely explains the absence of 600 MHz frequency spectrum antenna for wireless receivers.

---

**References:**

- [Everything You Need to Know About How the 600 MHz Wireless Auction Will Impact Filmmaking](https://nofilmschool.com/2017/11/how-600-mhz-wireless-auction-will-impact-filmmaking)
- [Guide to Wireless Microphone Operation](https://en-us.sennheiser.com/spectrum)

Comment: Mahendra, thanks! so, just a question, from the screenshot of `other antenna options for your receiver.`, i can choose the antenna that covers the item operational range 662-698, right? (btw, in my country, it's not restricted those frequencies).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, it should work.

The only concern that I have is [per the spec sheet](http://alss1.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ULX4PK.pdf), you're moving from a 1/2 wave antenna to a full wave antenna.

Looking at the other 1/2 wave antennas though, it appears that Shure has picked frequencies that don't overlap when looking at the full wave.  So I don't think that you'll see any cross channel issues when using the replacement full wave antenna.

The replacement full wave antenna is not likely tuned to the same frequency as the old 1/2 wave antenna.  So that could (will) impact the efficiency in transmit and receive, which translates into a decreased range for the device.